# Scroll Cell of UICollectionView to Left & Right direction by clicking on left & right button action

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I have requirement to make the UICollectionView Cell to be scroll to next 5 items from array by clicking on "right" button and show previous 5 times by clicking on "left button".

[image]

Can anyone help me by giving any suggestion to make it possbile in swift.

below is the code written, To show list on collection view in horizontal scroll.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.arrFalconList = ["ic_falcon_1","ic_falcon_2","ic_falcon_3","ic_falcon_4","ic_falcon_5","ic_falcon_6","ic_falcon_7"]
    }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrFalconList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let aFalconCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FalconCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FalconCollectionViewCell

        aFalconCell.imgFalcon.image = UIImage(named: self.arrFalconList[indexPath.row])
        aFalconCell.lblFalcon.text = self.arrFalconList[indexPath.row]
        aFalconCell.imgFalcon.layer.cornerRadius = ((aFalconCell.imgFalcon.frame.width) / 2)
        aFalconCell.imgFalcon.clipsToBounds = true

        if aFalconCell.isSelected {
            aFalconCell.imgFalcon.layer.borderColor = UIColor.init(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 55.0/255.0, blue: 61.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            aFalconCell.imgFalcon.layer.borderWidth = 2
        }else{
            aFalconCell.imgFalcon.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            aFalconCell.imgFalcon.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }


        return aFalconCell

    }
```

Please share your answer to handle the "left" & "right" button click event.

Answer (score 35):

I have found the solution for the query.

Below code will helpful to achive the requirement.

```
@IBAction func btnLeftArrowAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let collectionBounds = self.collectionView.bounds
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x - collectionBounds.size.width))
        self.moveCollectionToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

    }

    @IBAction func btnRightArrowAction(_ sender: Any) {

        let collectionBounds = self.collectionView.bounds
        let contentOffset = CGFloat(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + collectionBounds.size.width))
        self.moveCollectionToFrame(contentOffset: contentOffset)

    }

    func moveCollectionToFrame(contentOffset : CGFloat) {

        let frame: CGRect = CGRect(x : contentOffset ,y : self.collectionView.contentOffset.y ,width : self.collectionView.frame.width,height : self.collectionView.frame.height)
        self.collectionView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: how to archive same result in objective c. @Akash Thakkar

Answer (score 6):

akash 's answer in Objective-C, except I have made one slight change: I needed to scroll one cell at a time instead of scrolling all the way to the left or right. If you need that functionality change out

`float cellWidth = self.collectionView.visibleCells[0].bounds.size.width;`

with

`float collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.bounds;`

```
- (IBAction)scrollLeftAction:(id)sender
{
    float cellWidth = self.collectionView.visibleCells[0].bounds.size.width;
    float contentOffset = (float)(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x - cellWidth));
    [self moveCollectionViewToFrame:contentOffset];
}

- (IBAction)scrollRightAction:(id)sender
{
    float cellWidth = self.collectionView.visibleCells[0].bounds.size.width;
    float contentOffset = (float)(floor(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x + cellWidth));
    [self moveCollectionViewToFrame:contentOffset];
}

- (void)moveCollectionViewToFrame:(CGFloat)contentOffset
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(contentOffset, self.collectionView.contentOffset.y, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height);
    [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:frame
                                    animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
let I = 1
   func next_btn_clicked()
{
 clooectionview.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: (i) * clooectionview.frame.size.width, y: 0), animated: true)
I = I + 1
 }
```